# shutil can not find existing file using os.listdir

Tags: python, shutil, listdir

I have a big pool of images in which I folder them by using jpg filenames. Right now, I'm recieving:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'Z4554545.jpg'

However Z4554545.jpg exist within /images folder. What am I doing wrong here?
Note:I'm using Jupyter notebook.

```
path=r'C:/Users/images'
dst_dir=r'C:/Users/images/new'


for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file in id_final2:
        shutil.copy(file, dst_dir)
    elif file in id_final:
        shutil.copy(file, dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` does not include the path in the file, so if you are not running the script *in* C:/Users/images, shutil.copy will essentially try to copy the file from `os.curdir`

To fix your code:

```py
path=r'C:/Users/images'
dst_dir=r'C:/Users/images/new'


for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file in id_final2:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), dst_dir)
    elif file in id_final:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path=r'C:/Users/images'
dst_dir=r'C:/Users/images/new'
```

You need to give full paths. That is to to join the file name to the directory name.

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(dest_dir, file)
```